# How to Handle in code IllegalStateException on Cursor?

Tags: android

When I was debugging my application suddenly this error popup.
How can I handle this kind of error?

I don't know where and how is caused.

```
Daemon System Thread [<5> HeapWorker] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) 
    SQLiteCursor.finalize() line: 603   
    NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: You will need to let the crash occur so you can get a Java stack trace, which will point out where the error occurred.

Comment: I let the crash occur, but just this was showing up in my logs. My application was not having the focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use managedQuery() function to query the data. If you use managedQuery() instead of query() then Activity will keep the reference of the Cursor and automatically close it when it is not used.

Comment: How can I locate the cursors that were not started by managedQuery?

Comment: I don't know about how to locate the cursors that were not started by managedQuery(). Btw you can call the startManagingCursor() (activity method) for all the cursors that you are accessing. It will make sure that the activity will handle all the cursor management.

Comment: If I use a Cursor locally, and I .close() it. Do I have to manage it?

Comment: Any Cursor opened and not passed to startManagingCursor() has to be closed by yourself. If you close() all your cursors, that error shouldn't show up under your PID.

Comment: managedQuery(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
This method is deprecated. Use CursorLoader instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same 2 line Exception and stack trace when using a SQLiteDatabase Cursor because I forgot to close the cursor after populating a local database structure.